# Rewriting a c++ macro as a function, etc

Tags: c++, function, macros, conventions

I have a macro that I use a lot, inspired by another question:

```
#define to_string(x) dynamic_cast<ostringstream &> (( ostringstream() << setprecision(4) << dec << x )).str()
```

This one is extremely handy for example in use with functions taking string inputs:

```
some_function(to_string("The int is " << my_int));
```

However I've been told that using macros in C++ is bad practice, and in fact I've had problems getting the above to work on different compilers. Is there a way to write this as another construction, e.g. a function, where it will have the same versatility?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 and greater we now have [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).  We can use that to convert the data into a string an append it to whatever you want.

```
some_function("The int is " + std::to_string(my_int));
```

Comment: Thanks! But do I need to write it as above? That's a bit more messy than the original macro, and I'd have to rewrite quite a bit of code.

Comment: @jorgen yes.  This is not a direct replacement.  They way you have it with the macro is the only way I have seen that done without rewriting the code like above.

Answer (score 7):

Your macro has more possibilities than `std::to_string` offers. It accepts any sensible sequence of `<<` operators, sets a default precision and decimal base. A compatible way is to create a `std::ostringstream` wrapper that is implicitly convertible to `std::string`:

```
class Stringify {
    public:
        Stringify() : s() { s << std::setprecision(4) << std::dec; };

        template<class T>
        Stringify& operator<<(T t) { s << t; return *this; }

        operator std::string() { return s.str(); }
    private:
        std::ostringstream s;
};

void foo(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(Stringify() << "This is " << 2 << " and " << 3 << " and we can even use manipulators: " << std::setprecision(2) << 3.1234);
}
```

Live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14515cabae729875

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is what you want here.

Instead of: `to_string("The int is " << my_int)`

You can write: `"The int is " + to_string(my_int)`

This will return a `string`.

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/qxr9CZ)]